# PHP Use $ Operator in SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Basically What i Want to do is

```
<?php
$mynode = "Tag";
```

And i want to put it like this:

```
simplexml_load_file('foo.xml')->node1->$mynode;
```

Is there anyway of doing this?

Comment: Try `...->node1->{$mynode};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, suggest trying to not chain when relying on the success of something like `simplexml_load_file()`.  If `simplexml_load_file()` fails , it won't return a valid object to use, but a `boolean FALSE`.

Try something like below (and check for success between the load and such).

```
 $mynode = "Tag";
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('foo.xml');  //check for valid object after this 
 $node = $xml->node1;
 $whatever = $node->$mynode;
```

You have to be very careful chaining in PHP as most built in functions that deal with objects  aren't meant to gracefully handle chaining.

Comment: Thanks, But now im not going to bother with that silly method, im programming my own...